# Word or Phrase for a lack of "manual dexterity" (overall, including animals and humans)

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes the lack of ["manual dexterity"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/manual-dexterity) (humans, apes, similar animals).

Basically, most animals with paws, fins or hooves would usually fit into that category but it should also be applicable to a person with no fingers, hands or limbs.

Or, alternatively, a word for "(physically) unable to use tools due to lack of appropriate limbs (usually fingers)"

Is there a word or term for this?

Comment: I was expecting from the title that you would be looking for words meaning 'clumsy', I was going to offer the scottish 'handless' http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/handless but not I've read your question it seems needlessly unsubtle.

Comment: We call them "differently-abled", don't we?

Comment: @Spagirl "clumsy" was my first thought as well, but to me it implies accident-proneness, not a lack of the necessary limbs. Hm, what do you mean by unsubtle? I'm not a native english speaker, so I'm not quite sure how I could summarize it better; I tried to describe it as good as I could.

Comment: You could ironically use the phrase *all thumbs*.

Comment: @Katai  'Handless' in *Scottish* English usage figuratively means  clumsy, Literally it means 'without hands' but that is not what would be understood *in Scotland* if used to describe someone. Your heading, 'Word or phrase for 'lack of manual dexterity'...' sounds as though is is asking for a word for clumsy, (lack of dexterity) but it seems you are actually looking for a word for 'lack of hand'. So,*in Scots usage*, it would be rude to use 'handless', meaning clumsy, when its literal meaning was true. Perhaps you need to decide if the lack of digits or lack of dexterity is more important.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy you call fish 'differently-abled'?

Comment: @Spagirl in a sense, they are. They don't have to worry about education, employment, taxes and stuff. ;)

Comment: @Spagirl - I reckon OP wants a term applicable to human beings as they mention "unable to use tools...". It's unclear what tools at this point is, but I assumed and sought clarity whether or not OP is looking for a word that already exists. And yes, my assumption could well be wrong.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy He seems to want a term which can equally be applied to fish and to people who have lost all their limbs. Though I'm not sure that lack of using tools be your average goldfish is entirely down to the lack of fish-fingers alone. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Prehensile](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prehensile) means able to grab or hold something, and has the antonym [Nonprehensile](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonprehensile). This is probably the closest single word to describing an animal that is unable to use tools.

It seems to be commonly used in the world of [robotics](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node643.html), but could equally apply to animals.

Answer (score 1):

This may possibly be the closest to what you are looking for:

**maladroit** - lacking or showing a lack of nimbleness in using one's hands

Example: Some maladroit steering on her part caused the bicycle to go crashing into the bushes.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/maladroit

Another word that might prove useful would be:

**ambisinister** - clumsy or unskillful with both hands

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ambisinister

Comment: Though the OP does specifically want a term which 'applicable to a person with no fingers, hands or limbs', and its tricky to show a **lack** of nimbleness in using *one's hands* if one hasn't got any.

Comment: Point taken. However, I don't think the literal definition precludes it from being used in a more general sense. I can't see any problem using it in a phrase such as 'the bear's strikingly maladroit attempts to extract the honeycomb from the hole in the tree'.

Comment: if I was close enough to a bear to see how it was doing at honey extraction, I'd be nothing but complimentary! However, I think it would be strange to say that the reason a fish was bad with a screwdriver was maladroitness.

Comment: What would you put it down to? Lack of appropriate training?

Comment: I'd say it was 'due to lack of appropriate limbs',as per the question. I don't agree that 'maladroit' addresses the lack of hands, being essentially a synonym of **clumsy** which the Katai has already considered and rejected '*"clumsy" was my first thought as well, but to me it implies accident-proneness, not a lack of the necessary limbs*.'

Comment: I think we will simply have to agree to differ. I would say that while 'clumsy' may refer to a very broad range of meanings relating to overall movement, the broadest sense in which 'maladroit' could be used would be to refer to an inability to use the upper limbs / appendages with dexterity.